# Angular: Can someone explain ng build in reference to Angular IVY?

Tags: angular

I know Angular IVY uses AOT by default since Angular 9.
From googling, I understand that

```
ng build --dev uses JIT

ng build --prod uses AOT
```

Am trying to reconcile how these two options especially the first one (which uses JIT) works with Ivy Rendering Engine since its using AOT which seem to conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is a result of not understanding the difference between AOT/JIT and Ivy. Ivy is a rendering engine, which means that Ivy takes your templates (HTML) and transforms them into TypeScript (in simple terms). JIT/AOT are strategies for transforming generated TypeScript into JavaScript that can be read by the browser.

Comment: thanks. I am skirting the difference between Ivy saying "It uses AOT by default".  If I deploy my app using ng build --dev -> the documents say it uses JIT to compile the distro. when deployed on the browser and rendered, IVY kicks in. But the docs ALSO say IVY uses AOT (when we have built the app using JIT). Bit confused with these two

Comment: You misunderstood this, IVY is used before AOT/JIT, so this is not related. AOT and JIT relates to TypeScript, not template. So in JIT TypeScript is passed to browser with angular compiler (in the bundle) and during the runtime the typescript is compiled into JavaScript. With AOT, the translation from TypeScript to JavaScript is done during the build process.

Comment: thats what i thought too.. I was reading this document due to which I got confused https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-ivy-in-angular . In this he says------  
Ivy comes with many improvements, which include the following:
AOT compilation: Ahead of Time (AOT) compiles an app before it goes to a runtime environment like a browser. AOT reduces the load on the browser since it precompiles the app before it reaches the browser. ------ That made me think IVY has AOT compilation..so what will happen when I do ng build --dev which bundles using JIT?

Comment: The statement is partially correct, those are correct features of AOT, but AOT and Ivy are separate concepts. **AOT compilation** should be a separate paragraph, because it's not a part of Ivy. You can use it with Ivy. If you run `ng build --dev` then build process will use Ivy (if it's turned on in settings) to precompile templates and then JIT to ship TS to browser. Overall, what you'll see is faster build time, that's all. Everything still be working as expected. Faster, because JIT doesn't care about optimisation so much, that's why it's default during dev mode.

Comment: AOT compiles an app before sending to browser, which reduces workload for browser. JIT sends typescript with compiler in bundle to browser, so browser has to "compile" typescript. Ivy is used before those two, to change your templates (html) into typescript code that generates html. So, Ivy + AOT = translated to js, optimised, tree-shaked bundle. Ivy + JIT = not so optimised, partially translated, more workload for browser but much faster build, perfect for development mode (like `ng serve`).

Comment: thanks I just forgot. Lovely how I got two negatives for asking a question after i researched and didn't get. I totally appreciate your answers but I can see why SO community in general has a toxic reputation.